# Different behaviour from 1.1.2 to 1.2 in net/http

Tags: asynchronous, go, version

Before go 1.1.2 this code printed the last log.Println an executed the code afterwards, since 1.2 I had to run http.ListenAndServe() as a seperate go routine.
The changelog from 1.1.2 did not indicate any such changes nor do I know if this is the right way to have webserver running besides other code.

```
log.Println("Starting WebAPI Server")

http.HandleFunc("/", bot.httpHandler())
http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil) // with preceeding "go" in 1.2 to make my program working

log.Println("Started WebAPI Server")
```

Comment: [`http.ListenAndServe`](http://godoc.org/net/http#ListenAndServe) is blocking and was also blocking in Go 1.1.2.

Comment: `ListenAndServe` has an error return value that you aren't checking.  Is it possible that the call was failing when you tested it with Go 1.1.2? (e.g. if some other process was listening on port 8181)

Comment: @JamesHenstridge No my complete code executed without any error.

Comment: @JuliusF: so you checked the return value of `ListenAndServe` and it wasn't an error?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge yes. I had `err := http.ListenAndServer` and checked it's value. Like it's in the documentantion. I just removed the check from the example code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, but http.ListenAndServe has always blocked.

Comment: That is my experience too, but I got this behaviour. Since it now does not appear anymore it seems to be "fixed" for me. Maybe I got something wrong with the error checking.